# floating-point addition

Tags: numbers

Why am I getting these results?

```
(+ 5.2   42.4   -1) 46.6
(+ 5.2   42.45   -1) 46.650000000000006
```

Couldn't the 2nd operation just output `46.65`? Where does the `0000000000006` come from?

Comment: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://www.floating-point-gui.de/) explains everything very nicely.

Comment: Also this :) https://0.30000000000000004.com/

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing is a byproduct of binary [floating-point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic).  Non-integer decimal values generally don't have a representation in binary floating point that is truly equal.  For many applications the difference or inaccuracy in representation isn't important, so applications can leverage the flexibility and performance of that format.  The Emacs manual discusses number representation in elisp: [Numbers - GNU Emacs Lisp Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Numbers.html#Numbers).

Answer (score 0):

The most common floating point formats used on computers use binary.

so

```
5.2
```

in binary is

```
101.00110011001…
```

This sequence goes on forever, and because it cannot go on forever will be an approximation.

## Why is this?

10 has the factors 2 and 5, so all numbers n/m, where m has only the prime factors 2 and/or 5, can be represented without error. Other numbers will be rounder, e.g. n/3, n/7, n/9, n/11, n/12, n/13, n/14, n/15 n/17, … .

Binary is base 2
2 has the factors 2, so all numbers n/m, where m has only the prime factor 2, can be represented without error. So the the above list we add n/5, n/10, (n/15 is already included) n/20 etc.

You will note that it is only a few extra, but this can cause problems when numbers are displayed, and they are not what is expected.

Base 12 or 60 would be better, as they can be divided my more numbers, but still not all.